# Python Pandas: returning more then one field value when applying function to a data frame row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to apply several functions to data frame rows. Arguments of these functions take values from two or more fields of a single row. For example:

```
d = {                                                                                                       
  'a': [1,1,1,1],                                                                                           
  'b': [2,2,2,2],                                                                                           
  'c': [3,3,3,3],                                                                                           
  'd': [4,4,4,4]                                                                                            
}                                                                                                           

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)                                                                                       

def f1(x,y):                                                                                                
    return x + 2*y                                                                                          

def f2(x,y):                                                                                                
    return y + 2*x                                                                                          

df2 = pd.DataFrame()                                                                                        
df2['val1'] = df1.apply(lambda r: f1(r.a, r.b),1)                                                           
df2['val2'] = df1.apply(lambda r: f2(r.c, r.d),1)
```

When applying each function in turn, one after another, Pandas make a separate iteration over all data frame rows. In this example Pandas iterate data frame twice. As a result I get:

```
In [10]: df2                                                                                                
Out[10]:                                                                                                    
   val1  val2                                                                                               
0     5    10                                                                                               
1     5    10                                                                                               
2     5    10                                                                                               
3     5    10
```

Is there any way to apply two or more functions like this in a single pass over data frame? This way application should return value for more then one field in a row. Also, this case includes application of a single function returning values for more then one field. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your functions are linear or can be vectorized in some way, we can do many cool things.

```
t = pd.DataFrame(dict(val1=[1, 2, 0, 0], val2=[0, 0, 2, 1]), df1.columns)
df1.dot(t)
```

Or even quicker with

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df1.values.dot(
        np.array([[1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 2], [0, 1]])
    ),
    df1.index,
    ['val1', 'val2']
)
```

[image]

Or you can define a new function to apply

```
def f3(r):
    return pd.Series(dict(val1=f1(r.a, r.b), val2=f2(r.c, r.d)))

df1.apply(f3, 1)
```

Comment: Tried this one on a 74Mb csv file on my MacBookPro6,2, Intel Core i5, 2,53, Processors: 1, Cores:2, L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB, L3 Cache: 3 MB,Memory:4 GB. Under OSX EL Capitan Ver. 10.11.6. Works much worse then  one by one function application. Consumed about 6GB of total memory and never finished, had to kill. Aesthetically this solution looks great, most readable to me. I think this degradation is due to extra memory allocation that dictionary and series object require.

Comment: @zork good to know.  Are these the actual functions you need?  If they are, we can vectorize this easily.

Comment: Updated with some useful info

Answer (score 1):

You could fill them at the same time by combining your functions:

```
def f3(x,y,z,a):
    return x + 2*y, a + 2*z
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3['val1'], df3['val2'] = f3(df1.a, df1.b, df1.c, df1.d)
```

Comment: this is a good approach, not every function is possible to run like this over the dataFrame though.
It is also possible to do it like `df3['val1'], df3['val2'] = f1(df1.a, df1.b), f2(df1.c, df1.d)`

Comment: Does not work with my real functions and arguments. I get this error: '/Users/user/usr/anaconda_2.7/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   2670             if name in self._info_axis:
   2671                 return self[name]
-> 2672             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2673 
   2674     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
'

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create new functions, you can use one-liner below:

```
>>> df2 = df1.apply(lambda r: pd.Series({'val1': f1(r.a, r.b), 'val2': f2(r.c, r.d)}), axis=1)
>>> df2
   val1  val2
0     5    10
1     5    10
2     5    10
3     5    10
```